# How to write if else inside an if...else statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python and in this code i want to check if `bid_data[8]` not equal to '' then the below code runs otherwise only
`bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]` should runs

```
if (idx % 2 == 1):
    bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')

    bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]
    items = bid_data[8].split(":")[-1]
    qnty = int(bid_data[9].split(':')[1].strip())
    dept = (bid_data[10] + bid_data[15].strip()).split(":")[-1]
    edate = bid_data[20].split("End Date:")[-1]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you should find and go through a Python tutorial.

Comment: I dont get the question, could you please more specify it

Comment: You you need to check if `bid_data[8]` is not an empty string, just do a `if not bid_data[8]:`

Comment: There is no `else` statement in your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (idx % 2 == 1):
    bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')

    if bid_data[8] != '':
        bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]
        items = bid_data[8].split(":")[-1]
        qnty = int(bid_data[9].split(':')[1].strip())
        dept = (bid_data[10] + bid_data[15].strip()).split(":")[-1]
        edate = bid_data[20].split("End Date:")[-1]
    else:
        bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]
```

Comment: This can be simplified by moving the duplicate line outside of and before the inner if and removing the else case.

Comment: getting error local variable 'bid_data' referenced before assignment @RobH

Comment: He meant this line `bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]`. But then you wont need `else` as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. (And I did say to remove the `else`, since it's not needed after moving the duplicate line.) Thank you for clearing it up for the OP, @RishabhMishra

Comment: Right, but his main question was around writing else inside if....else, lol. So, that `else` is just for showing him how to do that in python.